# How to stop Visual Studio 2017 from opening browsers when launching project as a docker container

Tags: visual-studio-2017, docker-for-windows, docker

I've started a new project with Docker support.

How do I stop a browser window from opening when I start the project in Docker mode?

I hit F5 with "Docker" displayed next to the play icon on the tool bar and I always get a browser window open.

I've been into my project settings and turned off `Launch URL` for all project profiles.

[image]

I've also tried going into `launchSettings.json` and setting `"launchBrowser": false,` to try and stop it from happening. Note that changing the project properties does not seem to update the `launchSettings.json` file (annoyingly)!

This is really frustrating as for APIs I don't want a browser window to appear each time I start debugging. In fact, I don't want it for a website either as I typically have a window open that I refresh to see the changes.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 4):

I found how to fix it.

In the VS solution there is a `docker-compose` project.

1. Right click on the `docker-compose` project and select properties.
2. In the `General` tab find the `Launch Browser` option and set its value to `No`.